# Telegram бот не выводит кириллические символы

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('*токен*')

def tlist():
    tlist = ""
    with open(r"D:\Py\list.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            tlist += line
    return tlist

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == "/list":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, tlist())

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Вместо "имя1 имя2 имя3", бот выводит "РёРјСЏ1 РёРјСЏ2 РёРјСЏ3".
Кодировка текстового файла UTF-8. Пробовал использовать str и format, та же ерунда.
Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строку `with open(r"D:\Py\list.txt", "r") as file:` нужно добавить кодировку:

```
 with open(r"D:\Py\list.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
```

Должно помочь. А вообще нужно всегда указывать кодировку, меньше проблем будет.